# HTML в EditText

Tags: android, html, android-edittext

Могу ли я каким-либо образом форматировать EditText так, чтобы при нажатии на enter не просто курсор переносился на новую строку, а создавался новый абзац (к примеру тэг p). Это нужно для того, чтобы отступы между строками и абзацами были разными. Еще было бы неплохо менять цвет выделенного текста или делать его жирным, курсивным и т.д.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит рассмотреть Markdown вместо HTML для этих целей. Вот, например, либа - может подойдёт: https://github.com/noties/Markwon